# Can you create an external PHPdoc for a class?

Tags: php, ide, phpdoc

let's say I have the following

```
class Something extends ClassWithMagicMethods{}
```

Normally I would add a docblock for any properties I know exist even if accessed via a magic method

```
/**
 * @property string $someVar
 * @method SomeClass getSomeClass()
 */
class Something extends ClassWithMagicMethods{}
```

Which works great, but what I'm wondering is if we can have that docblock separate from the definition of the class. Two possible usecases:

- Third party package that doesn't include the docblock but I want autocompletion from my IDE - I'd like to be able to just add my own docblock somewhere for it.
- An extension system - In the file where the extension is defined I'd like to document the new properties this extension adds to the class.

I'm aware I could technically create a dummy `ide_helper.php` file that never actually gets run - just indexed by the IDE - unfortunately this causes any decent IDE to complain about duplicate declarations which I don't want as it also makes code navigation slower.

So - is it possible to document a PHP class by composing multiple docblocks external from the class definition?

Most of the results I've pulled up on SO are referencing just documenting unknown types where you use them which isn't what I need. I.E:

```
/** @var Something $something */
$something = FactoryMethodThing::create('Something');
```

Comment: No, the doc block is read by most doc block parsers in conjunction with the class. To be fair, a *decent IDE* wouldn't need doc blocks to offer autocompletion. The autocomplete can be offered directly from code if the IDE is capable tokenizing and lexing the code (*for example phpstorm does this*). Additionally, it makes no sense to read a doc block for a class that does not exist.

Comment: @Sherif I use PHPstorm, but I'm talking explicitly about dynamic properties and methods that aren't actually in the code (a good example is an ORM class where the properties aren't defined).

Comment: I can understand that, but what sense does it make to have a doc block sitting around for a class that doesn't exist in your code? Usually the doc block is read in conjunction with the class because the parser can then associate the doc block with that class. Trying to separate them makes little sense in practice.

Comment: Also, any properties that are dynamically generated in code are going to be impossible to document given that they are dependent on knowing information about the runtime. doc blocks are typically based on static analysis rules which don't require any knowledge of the runtime. Sorry to be the barer of bad news, but the notion doesn't bode well in practice.

Comment: You're skipping over the two use cases I mentioned above though, a third party package (think composer) that doesn't have them documented, or an extension system so the original class doesn't know about the new properties that your extension is adding, but the extension obviously does (I'm not referring to `classB extends classA` I'm referring to an injection based extension system), There are valid use cases for such a thing. Another good example would be documenting a Guzzle service factory since those classes are entirely generated at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you :

```
phpdoc -d path/to/my/project -f path/to/an/additional/file -t path/to/my/output/folder
```

Source: http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/running-phpdocumentor.html